# Criminal news stories

Tags: data-request, media

Any open data sources containing collections of criminal news stories across a wide variety of newspapers?

I know there are a lot of newspaper archives but I can't seem to find any that allow you to sort by 'crime' articles. (I'm interested in contemporary stories, last 10-20 years, but more recent the better. )

Answer (score 4):

Here are some resources for searching across newspaper archival records for "crime stories", as well as some non-open (noopen) data solutions, and some references. resources, and thoughts:

## Open Data

[Some databases are newspapers - Enoch Pratt Free Library](http://www.prattlibrary.org/research/database/?sbj=998)
[Baltimore Sun Archive - 1837-Current (1837-1988 Article Image Search, 1989-Current Article Text Search)](http://pqasb.pqarchiver.com/baltsun/advancedsearch.html)
[Search Results for "Crime" 75361 Results - Baltimore Sun Archive 1837-1988](http://pqasb.pqarchiver.com/baltsun/results.html?st=advanced&QryTxt=crime&type=historic&sortby=RELEVANCE&datetype=0&frommonth=05&fromday=17&fromyear=1837&tomonth=12&today=31&toyear=1988&By=&Title=&at_hist=article)
[Archive for 'Rediscovered Crime News' - HistoricalCrimeDetective.com](http://www.historicalcrimedetective.com/category/rediscovered-crime-news/)
[The St. Louis Evening Whirl - An Uninterrupted Crime-Fighting Publication Since 1938](http://web.archive.org/web/20121002072840/http://thewhirlonline.com/home/index.php)
[Indianapolis Newspapers Database,  1848-1991](https://www.statelib.lib.in.us/IndyNews/1848_1991_search.asp)
[69 Pages. Total number of records = 1021](https://www.statelib.lib.in.us/IndyNews/1848_1991_results.asp?pagenum=69)
[New Jersey Newspaper Archives - Free and Paid](http://www.nj.com/archive/)
[List of Online Newspaper Archives - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:List_of_online_newspaper_archives)
[Culture Crime - A database of antiquities and art crime](http://news.culturecrime.org/)
[Crime, Punishment, and Popular Culture, 1790-1920](http://gale.cengage.co.uk/crime-punishment-17901920.aspx)
[Unthinkable Crimes - Archival and Library Resources](http://libguides.wustl.edu/crimes)

## Not Open Data Solutions

[The British Newspaper Archive](http://www.britishnewspaperarchive.co.uk/) and the [The Sacramento Bee's Archive Search - Search The Bee's Archive, 1984 to present (fee-based)](http://www.sacbee.com/site-services/archives/) offer extensive archives that are locked up behind paywalls:
[Britisih Newspaper Archive Search Results for 'Crime'](http://www.britishnewspaperarchive.co.uk/search/results?basicsearch=crime)
[Archive Search Results - Searched for: '(crime) AND date(all)'. (Showing 25 of 40365 articles)](http://nl.newsbank.com/nl-search/we/Archives?p_product=SB&p_theme=sb&p_action=search&p_maxdocs=200&s_dispstring=(crime)%20AND%20date(all)&p_field_advanced-0=&p_text_advanced-0=(%22crime%22)&xcal_numdocs=50&p_perpage=25&p_sort=YMD_date:D&xcal_useweights=no)
[Michigan Newspaper Archives - Pay to Search Many Different Paper Archives](http://blog.mlive.com/mlive_special_sections/page/newspaper_archives.html)
[The Dallas Morning News Archive](http://ece.dallasnews.com/archive/)
[Searched for: crime AND date(all) Returned: 20 displays of 76425 matches.](http://nl.newsbank.com/nl-search/we/Archives?p_product=DM&p_theme=dm&p_action=search&p_maxdocs=200&s_hidethis=no&p_field_label-0=Author&p_field_label-1=title&p_bool_label-1=AND&p_field_label-2=Section&p_bool_label-2=AND&s_dispstring=crime%20AND%20date(all)&p_field_advanced-0=&p_text_advanced-0=(%22crime%22)&xcal_numdocs=40&p_perpage=20&p_sort=YMD_date:A&xcal_useweights=no)
[San Jose Mercury News Archives](http://www.mercurynews.com/archive-search/)
[1423 articles matching "allfields(crime) AND date(1985)" were found in San Jose Mercury News Archives](http://nl.newsbank.com/nl-search/we/Archives?p_product=SJ&p_theme=sj&p_action=search&p_maxdocs=200&s_dispstring=allfields(crime)%20AND%20date(1985)&p_field_date-0=YMD_date&p_params_date-0=date:B,E&p_text_date-0=1985&p_field_advanced-0=&p_text_advanced-0=(%22crime%22)&xcal_numdocs=20&p_perpage=10&p_sort=YMD_date:D&xcal_useweights=no)

### Extra

[How to use the Baltimore Sun Archives and the library to search for old murder cases (and other stuff)](http://chamspage.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-to-use-baltimore-sun-archives-and.html)
[Use the Local Memory Project to find a more diverse array of Periodicals](http://www.localmemory.org/#USA/22205/1000/)

Many newspapers run their own crime/crime reports database in house; I'm assuming that blurb copy doesn't count as a "news story", but these can be useful for tracking down new sources and leads, and cross-referencing, to say the least. Here are a few:
[Gotcha! Crime News From Central Virginia - Richmond Times-Dispatch](http://www.richmond.com/gotcha/)
[Virginia Beach Crime - The Virginian Pilot](http://hamptonroads.com/newsdata/crime/virginia-beach/)
[Crime Incident Information Center - Richmond Police Department](http://eservices.ci.richmond.va.us/applications/crimeinfo/index.asp)
[Crime - The State](http://www.thestate.com/news/local/crime/)
[Crime/Courts - Canton Rep](http://www.cantonrep.com/news/crime-courts)
[Crime - Indy Star](http://www.indystar.com/news/crime/)
[Crime - News Press](http://www.news-press.com/news/crime/)
[Police Reports - Syracuse](http://www.syracuse.com/crime/police-reports/)
[Crime/Courts Database - The Review](http://www.the-review.com/section/crime%20&%20courts%20database)